# Laravel 5.4 Save last login in logs table

Tags: php, laravel, events

I want to save a log register in my table `logs_users` when an user make the login successfully. For make this, logs_users table have the next fields:

```
+id
+user_id: Id of the user
+log_id :Number that represents the log( in this case, the number is 2)
+created_at
```

I dont understand how I can make this using the events in laravel 5.4 so if you can tell me the steps I will thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `authenticated` method in the `Auth\LoginController`, something like:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    auth()->user()->logsUsers()->create();
}
```

I assume you already defined `logsUsers()` relationship. If not, do that:

```
public function logsUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LogsUser::class);
}
```